# Compare multiple words in same textbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I m trying to make a simple lexical analyzer in c#.

i have 2 rich text boxes, 1st box will have the code as input and the 2nd box will display the output.

code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("public"))
            richTextBox2.Text = "public= id";
        if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("main"))
            richTextBox2.Text = "main = id";
        if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("void"))
            richTextBox2.Text = "void = id";
}
```

it always shows only 1 match..
if my input is "public static void main"
it shows only "public = id" in richtextbox2.

why not display main or void ?

i m a newbie, any help will be appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: you mean it only shows "void = id", right?

Comment: you are overwriting the contents of the richTextBox2.Text each time, so only your last instruction defines the text

Comment: use `richTextBox2.Text + = `

Comment: The `=` operator is also called the [assignment-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx), so it assigns a value, it does not append it. Therefore use the [+= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

you should use `AppendText` instead. i.e:

```
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("public"))
        richTextBox2.AppendText("public= id");
```

`richTextBox2.Text = "someText"` actually sets the Text of richtextbox to "someText". so for each satisfying `if` condition of your code, your richtextobx2 text will be overwritten

Comment: 1+ (although `could` would be better than `should` because `+=` works also). Didn't know `AppendText`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have "public static void main" on your text box, your code will show "void = id".
This is because every time your code founds the string it is looking for, it will REPLACE the text in the box value.

So, to change this, instead of using:

```
richTextBox2.Text = ...
```

use

```
richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox2.Text + ...
```

or

```
richTextBox2.Text += ...
```

This way you will ADD the text to the text box.